# What is relevant way to Migrate EF 6.0 to EF Core relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

As i am migrating from Ef 6.0 to EF code ...I am dealing with relatioship.
Below code works fine in EF 6.0 however not in EF Core

```
public class User_MastMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<User_Mast>
{
            public User_MastMap()
            {


                HasMany(e => e.CallEntryDetail)
                  .WithOptional(e => e.CreateByUser)
                  .HasForeignKey(e => e.CreatedBy);
             }
    }
```

I have tried below code using EF Core functionality.
It gets build succeeded but throwing an error.

```
  public class User_MastMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User_Mast>
    {
        public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<User_Mast> builder)
        {

        builder.HasMany(e => e.CallEntryDetail)
              .WithOne(e => e.CreateByUser)
              .HasForeignKey(e => e.CreatedBy);
        }
     }
```

Error :

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property  'CallEntry.CreateByUser' of type 'User_Mast'. Either
>   manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the
>   model.

Comment: Please post a minimal complete repro.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Can you suggest what i am doing wrong defining this ?

Comment: Perhaps, if you post a minimal complete repro.

Comment: I have used WithOne instead Withoptional... Is that correct way of doing this ?

Comment: Are you sure this is configuration is actually being used by EF? The only time I've seen that error is with M2M relationships, which EF Core doesn't currently support (hence the error). However, you're configuring a one-to-many here, so I can only assume EF isn't actually seeing it.

Comment: Could you show the screen shot of database diagram between User_Mast and CallEntryDetail?

Comment: Have you even added the `User_MastMap` to your Context inside the configuration?  It doesn't happen automatically

Comment: Also this functionality isn't even added out of the box in current stable releases. It will come in EF Core 2.0 (see [this pull request](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/6989) added for preview1). You still need to call `ApplyConfiguration<T>` inside your DbContext's configuration method